# how to use wavefront .obj files in c++ without using openGL

Tags: c++

I am starting with 3D objects in C++. There are many tutorials on OpenGL on the internet but I wanted to know: How can you render basic 3D shapes in C++ without using OpenGL. I will be using .obj files so I wanted to know how to import and export these files without OpenGL.

Comment: Write your own 3D render from scratch.  OpenGL has no facilities to read/write .obj files, so you also need to write your own code for that as well.

Comment: What you are planning to do ist quite complex. Be prepared, to dive deep into the math behind 3d rendering.

Comment: What you're planning to do isn't that complex really (but it will help if you use a matrix library, eg. eigen). I bet there are plenty of readily available OBJ loaders for you to use, but you could even just write your own. The format isn't that complex either. Neither of these things are really suited to a stackoverflow question, however. Do feel free to come back once you've tried something, if you're still stuck.

Comment: +Rook, I am doing a research on naive spheres. So, my mentor told me that we can build a 3D shape in C++ without using openGL. We just have to write to the obj files, the values of of the vertices and we can generate the faces and normals using that. Further, we just have to cout that file.

Comment: So, I just want to know the format to import and export the obj files and how to open and use them.